How to load server-side data into my NextJS application at startup for future use
I have a NextJS application that makes server-side calls to a database to get base information. Due to the nature of the data I would like it to be loaded once at initial runtime and then be retained in a variable for use later.
What is the best way to action this?

Your question is very broad. My first guess would be either using a useContext or a global state management tool that stores the fetched data. If you could give more specifics it would be helpful.
For example, is the NextJS going to run server side primarily or not? How does the Data look like, and how do you fetch data? Are you using GraphQL or REST? Are you going to use a global state manager?

Hi, the data will purely be used server-side so can't use Context. I have a function that obtains the data from a psql database. I'm not currently using a global state manager. I believe I need something like Context but on the server side

Ok, do you mean the NextJS API when talking about server-side? So outside any component or page?

Yeah, something I can run once to get the data on load (server side) and then reuse in other locations and functions (server side)
